# php limit mail ()

Tags: php, email

this might be easy but I don´t see the way. I have a shopping cart at my side where user can buy things. for this the buyer can  imput his email-adress into an input-form. the order is sent with php `mail()` to the shopowner and the buyer.

I´m looking for a way to limit mail to sent only two email, this for preventing spam.
I see the risk that spammers could input a semicolon string like this:

```
email@examplecom;email@xxyz.com;hans@jdkdl.com
```

Comment: standard email separator is comma "," not semicolon ";".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the number of email in the string like this:

```
if(count(explode(';',$emailList))<3)
{
    // send email
}
else
{
    // Oh no, jumbo!
}
```

This code will [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your email string based on the `;` characters into an array while at the same time use a [count](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function on the array and execute one of two scenarios based on the number.

Answer (score 5):

Y can't you validate using .

```
$validemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($validemail) {
  $headers .= "Reply-to: $validemail\r\n";
}else
{
//redirect.
}
```

considering your actual question .

```
<?php
$emails = explode(';',$emailList);
if(count ($emails)<3)
{
if(filter_var_array($emails, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    mail();
    }
  else
    {
    //die    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: he is worried about email injection .so this may help him

Comment: But the first thing is, he wants to limit the number of mails. That was the primary question.

Comment: Hi, right I worried about email injection. this works great, thanks. t

Answer (score 0):

This should work to only pick maximum two emails (the first two):

```
$emailString = "email@examplecom;email@xxyz.com;hans@jdkdl.com";
$emails = explode(";", $emailString);
$emails = array_slice($emails, 0, 2);
$emailString = implode(";", $emails);
var_dump($emailString);
```

Outputs:

```
string(31) "email@examplecom;email@xxyz.com"
```